# Uncaught TypeError: layer.onAdd is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

First attempt at working with Leaflet to display and work with a dynamic map, and I'm running into an error when I attempt to add a new layer of markers to a LayerGroup.

Here is my Map object, encapsulating the functionality of leaflet:

```
function Map() {
  //properties/fields
  var map;
  var layers = [];  

  return {
    setMap: function(aMap) {map=aMap;},
    setView: function(aView) {map.setView(aView);},
    addLayer: function(aLayer, name) {layers[name] = aLayer; map.addLayer(aLayer);},    
    addListings: function(anArr, name) {
        var mLayer = [];                                           
        for (var i = 0; i < anArr.length; i++) {
            var aMarker = L.marker([anArr[i][0], anArr[i][1]]);
            mLayer.push(aMarker);                            
        };
        layers[name] = L.layerGroup(mLayer);
        layers[name].addTo(map);
    },
    updateListings: function(anArr, name) {
        var mLayer = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < anArr.length; i++) {
            console.log(anArr[i].entity.locations[0].lat, anArr[i].entity.locations[0].lng);
            var aMarker = L.marker(anArr[i].entity.locations[0].lat, anArr[i].entity.locations[0].lng);
            mLayer.push(aMarker);
        }
        layers[name].addLayer(mLayer);
    },
    clearLayer: function(name) { layers[name].clearLayers(); },
  };
}
```

When I load the map initially, everything's fine:

```
                myMap.setMap(L.map('tikit-map').setView([{{ $result['lat'] }}, {{ $result['lng'] }}], 12));                        
                var listLocation = [];
                @foreach ($result['company'] as $facility)                        
                    listLocation.push([{{ $facility['entity']['locations'][0]['lat'] }}, {{ $facility['entity']['locations'][0]['lng'] }}]);                            
                @endforeach  
                myMap.addListings(listLocation, 'listings');
```

Then, when I need to refresh the screen (and the map) via an ajax call (with data coming back via the variable companies, I get the error:

```
myMap.clearLayer('listings');
myMap.updateListings(companies, 'listings');
```

The error specifically occurs in the line:

`layers[name].addLayer(mLayer);`

of updateListings

Anyone with some experience with leaflet that can offer some advice? Thanks

> UPDATE: The issue I'm having revolves about why I can't "reuse" the
>   LayerGroup after I've cleared it, and how I would go about doing that. I've 
>   struggled through the first half of this day for a solution and was
>   about to post the code as a demo on jsfiddle when I came across this:
>   https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/FAQ.md **You can add the
>   Google Maps API as a Leaflet layer with a plugin. But note that the
>   map experience will not be perfect, because Leaflet will just act as a
>   proxy to the Google Maps JS engine, so you won't get all the
>   performance and usability benefits of using Leaflet when the Google
>   layer is on.**
>
> Because the requirement of the project is to use Google maps, I am
>   abandoning my efforts, perhaps someone needing to do this will benefit
>   from any future answers.

Comment: An online demo is always the best way to debug...

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a plain vanilla javascript array with `var mLayer = [];`, when you really need to be using the Leaflet construct for arrays of layers, which is either `L.layerGroup` or `L.featureGroup` - depending on the amount of interactivity. It sounds like for your usecase, `var mLayer = L.layerGroup` would be fine.